# How to make a messenger chat bot without a facebook app and webhook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-webhooks

I went through the documentation for creating a chatbot for messenger platform.

All I find there, I need a server, which in the case used as a service for the Facebook platform.

The server also validates the webhook from facebook app.

Now I see, for a chatbot, I need a facebook app, webhook server and definitely a facebook page.

Then I find an application [Flow XO](https://flowxo.com/), where I only put the page name and the bot is ready.

My question is, how they([flow.xo](https://flowxo.com/)) can communicate facebook page without a Facebook app(appId, appSecret) and webHook.

Comment: they do have an app and a webhook. you are basically using THEIR bot, not your own one.

Comment: How they automatically subscribe to my page with their app? Is there any API to subscribe to a page to an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how they can communicate facebook page without a Facebook app(appId, appSecret) and webHook.

They can’t.

They use *their* server and *their* app to communicate with the API, on behalf of the users that grant them access to their pages, by providing the necessary permissions when they log in to that app.

Comment: So, Are they use their own Facebook app, add messenger as a product and then subscribe to my page?

Comment: Yes, that’s how page managing apps work. You grant their app permission to act on behalf of your page, by logging in to it and granting it the necessary permissions.

Comment: Is there only a single app to subscribe all pages?

Comment: They might use several app ids to spread the load a bit, but they surely won’t create an individual app id for every single user (because then they would have to go through the review process every single time as well.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Are there any API, so I can subscribe to a page with my app?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook allows to create a Facebook App which integrates multiple chatbots. At [Amio](https://amio.io), we ask you for permission using Facebook OAuth. When you give us these permissions we send and receive message on your behalf. This allows you to create a chatbot using Amio API without need of creating a Facebook App.

Facebook Page is always needed as this is the entry point of users interacting with your bot. You can check [Amio documentation](https://docs.amio.io/docs/facebook-messenger-getting-started) for more detail.